# Looking for a low-power, low-footprint WiFi solution

Tags: wireless, kodi, media-server, android, headless

I am working on turning my Pi into a "Car-puter," and will be using one of the Pi-specific XBMC images (Xbian, Raspbian, perhaps OpenELEC).  I would like to use the XBMC Android Remote app to be able to avoid having to have a monitor, mouse, or keyboard.

My question is, **what would the best way to establish a WiFi connection between the phone and the Pi?**

Right now my thought is to get a USB wireless dongle that supports ad-hoc, and then finding a way to get my rooted phone to support ad-hoc as well.  Is this a reasonable route to go, or is there something easier/better? If that is a good way to go, are there any models that are recommended for this sort of situation? (I'm not extremely knowledgeable with networking)

I will be using a powered USB hub for all the devices I'll be connecting, so I'm not too worried about power draw. Also, I'll be keeping all the devices behind the dash board, so a full-sized router is out of the question.

Comment: Why not use [xbmc-remote-android](http://code.google.com/p/xbmc-remote-android/) and use bluetooth instead of WiFi?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had some success networking between the Pi and a phone using a wifi dongle supporting adhoc. Essentially, you set up the Pi as an access point using hostapd and run a DHCP server on the Pi to give an IP address.

I've just posted the details on my blog at www.recantha.co.uk/blog.
Didn't really want to paste it all in here because I'm not sure how to get the preformatting working yet.

[Blog post here](http://www.recantha.co.uk/blog/?p=317)

Comment: Those scripts look like just what I need. I'll let you know if they work on my device!

Answer (score 2):

BT is a pain in the ass for everything that is not sharing a photo with another phone or having a call on your headset. BT is not for general purpose networking.

WiFi is the right choice, but the mode you are looking for is [`infrastructure-AP`](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Documentation/modes#AccessPoint_.28AP.29_infrastructure_mode) so that your Pi will become a real access point. So be really really careful about what dongle you buy. There are many combinations of drivers/chips that don't support AP nor ad-hoc network creation (mostly Broadcom AFAIK). I strongly suggest to pick up an Atheros or RT73 chip for this kind of things (even if it's hard to find Atheros chips inside USB dongles).

For example [this](http://www.modem-help.co.uk/D-Link/DWL-G122-AirPlus-G-11bg-WLAN-USB-Adapter--rev-C-.html) *should* work because of its RT73 chip (as stated [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1104914), [here](http://forum.lowyat.net/topic/849777/all) and [here](http://legacy.tonymacx86.com/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=52187)). If you want to buy another dongle with another chip, then you'll have to investigate yourself if the chip supports infrastructure-AP mode.